# border BottonAppBar flutter

Tags: android, flutter, curve

how to apply curve in the BottonAppBar, just for this button?

I want to do this:
[image]

My code:
[image]

Comment: Please do not screenshot your code, copy and paste it here

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it through this plugin.
Just go through the plugin documentation it's quite simple.

https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one for your desired bottom bar. https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar